# Format Exception when trying to convert

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

So I'm trying to read from a text file and store each field into an array. But when I tried to convert accountNumber to an Int, I get an error.

```
     public bool matchCustomer(int accountID){
        string[] data = null;
        string line = Global.currentFile.reader.ReadLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
            data = line.Split('*');
            this.accountNumber = Convert.ToInt32(data[0]);
            line = Global.currentFile.reader.ReadLine();
            if (accountID == this.accountNumber)
            {
                return true;
            }

          }

        return false;
       }
```

Comment: What error, and what is the value of `data[0]`?

Comment: The error says "Input string was not in a correct format." And the value of data[0] is 12345. The first line of the text file is 12345 * Shrek * 1209 * 100,000 * 50,000

Comment: If the values are all numeric, are there any values with more that 10 digits? (specifically, any greater than `2,147,483,647`)

Answer (score 1):

That's because data[0] isn't convertible into an int. What is data[0] at runtime?

You could use:

```
int value;
if(Int32.TryParse(data[0], out value))
{
  accountNumber = value;
}
else
{
  //Something when data[0] can't be turned into an int.
  //You'll have to decide this logic.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Likely, because you split by delimiter * in the string:

```
12345 * Shrek * 1209 * 100,000 * 50,000
```

You left with a spaced number "12345 " instead of all numbers "12345". This causes it to be unconvertible. Try to apply Trim:

```
 this.accountNumber = Convert.ToInt32(data[0].Trim());
```

Also, beware of strings with thousands separator comma (50,000 and 100,000). You might need to replace it with empty string if it is unconvertible:

```
data[4].Replace(",","").Trim();
```

Comment: I suspected the space, but testing via a console app shows that Convert.ToIn32(..) is smart enough to trim. However you're correct that it cannot properly catch the commas.

Comment: It is good that you can test it. :) I am not with my laptop right now. Sometimes this seemingly correct format gives us problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Other two answers addressed the issue and fix, I thought of providing another alternative which uses `Linq`.

You can replace complete `while` block content with this.

```
return line.Split('*').Select(s=> s.Trim().Replace(",", ""))
            .Where(c=> Regex.IsMatch(c.Trim(), @"\d+"))
            .Select(s=>int.Parse(s.Trim()))            
            .Any(e=>e == accountId);
```

Working [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KDH5I2)